# AspNet + IE8: auth cookie not always set

Tags: asp.net, cookies, internet-explorer-8, forms-authentication

Background:

- AspNet C# 3.5 Web App
- IIS 7
- Forms Authentication
- in *web.config*, no "domain" in `<forms />` settings
- name of cookie: .exampleAuth

Sometimes, and only with IE8, session auth cookie is not set in browser. The user logs in, he can see the default.aspx page of the web app, but if he clicks anywhere he is disconnected. No  auth cookie. `AspNet_SessionId` cookie is well created, as another one managed by our app.

It looks like it's happening since we removed the "domain" attribute in `Web.Config` to allow `example.com` and `example2.net` url for the web app.

Cookie is created using `FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(user.Id, true);` as before.

IE7, IE9, FF, Chrome are ok. IE8 sometimes (let's say 95% of the time it's ok, 5% user is disconnected). For some users, closing IE8 (without flushing cookie and cache) solves the problem.

One more thing: if we enable IE8 "cookie alert popup", we can see that auth cookie is **sometimes** set twice after login. First with `Expiration=Session`, then with `Expiration=Now+1h20` (session is set to 200 !)

Comment: from the moment you remove the domain from the web config the cookie if made on any name find on the url. So if you start your page with xxx.com, and then return it to www.xxx.com, the cookie is lost.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but that's not the issue: user stays on same url, and bug is only happenning with **IE8**!

Comment: Does the URL you are using have an underscore in it?

Comment: no, there isn't any underscore.